# Magento Product Attributes in top navigation

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the product attribute 'brand' in the drop down navigation. I can get the attributes to appear with the following code however the problem is brand attributes that are not relevant to certain categories are appearing in the category drop down. So what I need is for the brand attribute to only appear in a category when there are products in that category with the brand attribute. eg. brand 'seiko' will appear in the watches category drop down but not the necklaces category drop down. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<ul class="nav container">
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';

        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
    ?>
        <?php // Top level Nav - categories  ?>
        <li>
            <?php $_categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());?>
            <?php $catUrl = $_categoryModel->getUrl(); ?>
            <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>

            <div>
                <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
                <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>

                    <?php // Drop downs to subcategories - works fine. ?>
                    <div class="one-third column mega-menu">
                        <p class="menu-header">Category</p>
                        <ul class="twelve columns">
                            <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                                <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php
                                        $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                        echo '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '</a>';
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php // Drop downs to brand attribute - currently displays all brands not just relevant ones  ?>
                    <div class="one-third column mega-menu">
                        <p class="menu-header">Brand</p>
                        <ul class="twelve columns">
                            <?php
                                $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
                                $layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()));
                                $nodeId = $_category->getId();
                                $id = str_replace('category-node-', '', $nodeId);
                                $validAttributes = array();
                                foreach ($layer->getFilterableAttributes() as $attribute) {

                                    //I think this is where the validation needs to go but I dont know how to get only products within the category with brand attributes
                                   $validAttributes[] = $attribute;
                                }
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach($validAttributes as $validAttribute) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    if ($validAttribute->getAttributeCode() == 'brand') {
                                        $options = $validAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                                        foreach ($options as $option) {
                                            $productCount = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->groupByAttribute('country_of_manufacture')
            ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("cnt_product",'COUNT({{entity_id}})', 'entity_id')
            ->load();

                                            if (count($option) > 0) {
                                                $optionNodeId = 'attribute-'.$id.'-'.$validAttribute->getId().'-'.$option['value'];
                                                $data = array(
                                                    'name' => $option['label'],
                                                    'id' => $optionNodeId,
                                                    'url' => $catUrl.'?'.$validAttribute->getAttributeCode().'='.$option['value']
                                                );
                                                echo '<li><a href="'.$data['url'].'">'.$data['name'].'</a></li>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive figured it out for anybody that is interested.. I wasnt validating the attribute options against the product collection, below is the corrected code.

```
<?php foreach($validAttributes as $validAttribute) : ?>
     <?php
          if ($validAttribute->getAttributeCode() == 'brand') {
              $options = $validAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
              foreach ($options as $option) {

                 //Validate the product collection against each attribute option                                                
                 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
                 $collection->addCategoryFilter($_categoryModel);
                 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand',$option);

                 //if the count is greater than 0 after the collection has been filtered by category and product attribute option, echo the attribute.
                 if (count($collection) > 0) {
                     $optionNodeId = 'attribute-'.$id.'-'.$validAttribute->getId().'-'.$option['value'];
                     $data = array(
                           'name' => $option['label'],
                           'id' => $optionNodeId,
                           'url' => $catUrl.'?'.$validAttribute->getAttributeCode().'='.$option['value']
                     );
                     echo '<li><a href="'.$data['url'].'">'.$data['name'].'</a></li>';
                  }
              }
          }
     ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Warning: this is guaranteed to be slow. You should generate this once a day or something.

Comment: would you be able to suggest a quicker method? Ive been racking my brains on this one all day @Fuser97381

Comment: Nothing is quick in magento, so you have to cache everything. Generate your nav in a cron, and off-load it that way. The only way to make magento fast is to use as little magento as possible.